# jQuery lazy loading custom event or other suggestions?

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I am really new to jQuery but am helping a client with an issue on their website (had previously helped them with a non-jQuery problem) The initial login required is: username: shelliesimon / password: **t3$t2012** http://bit.ly/LhcG13  (under Sign in)

It should then load a page which is a Lightbox gallery that has been customised to show images in a slider as well enabling custom thumbnails that can be clicked at the bottom for the client to select and email.

The issue the client has is that when the image has too many photos, the 'pre-loading' of the larger images causes the browser to slow down (CPU usage rockets) and its hard to navigate. So I thought that perhaps Lazy loading would be the way forward (given that it is jQuery based)

I have had limited success in using this method after including the script from the jQuery Lazy Load website and changing the source to use data-original etc. and think the key may be in using a custom event  - I have tried 'click' as demonstrated in the documentation, but this requires the user to 'click' on the thumbnail and then again on the non-preloaded image at the top.

This also means that the original slider functionality stopped working.

I am at a bit of a loss as to what to do next in terms of finding out what 'event' is the custom event on this page and how to access it. Another approach is that I am still trying to decipher this suggestion to modify the cycle plugin http://www.anotherwebdevblog.com/simple-jquery-cycle-lazy-load-solution/) and would really appreciate any suggestions or comments from experts and others who are far more knowledgeable.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Try something simpler such as a [CSS lightbox](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/playboxv2.html#close) or [CSS lazy-loading](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/content-gallery.html).